# Image src empty after migration

Tags: migration

I have custom post types which holds images url, and displays it on homepage. 
After I moved my website from one domain to another changed servers as well, the url in admin panel are all fine in custom fields when I copy that and paste into browser image is visible, but on homepage images url are empty

```
 <img src alt="text">
```

Does anyone know what happend, I moved a lot of wordpress sites and never had met something like that before.

EDITION

It's normal custom type:

arguments for function

```
   $args = array( 
    'labels' => $labels,
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'supports' => array( 'title', 'revisions' ),
    'public' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus' => false,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'exclude_from_search' => true,
    'has_archive' => false,
    'query_var' => true,
    'can_export' => true,
    'rewrite' => true,
    'menu_icon' => get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/admin/icon-slider.png',
    'capability_type' => 'post'
);

register_post_type( 'sequenceslider', $args );
}
```

arguments for image field

```
         $prefix = 'iweb_';

         array(
        'name' => __('Sequence background image (Only works for Homepage 1, 4 and 5)', 'iwebtheme'),
        'desc' => __('Upload an image for sequence slider background.', 'iwebtheme'),
        'id' => $prefix.'seq_bgimage',
        "type" => "text",
        'std' => ''
    ),
```

echo call

```
 $bg = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'iweb_seq_bgimage', TRUE);
 <img class="bg-slide" src="<?php echo $bg; ?>" alt="" />
```

but actually i don't think it's related to custom posts, english version works fine, the other language not, and when I tried to migrate this site to another domain and host, even posts featured images stopped being displayed. 
It's not website I've done, just need to migrate it, but something seems hardcoded or I'm just dumb. Site address http://bpr.codemydesign.pl/

Comment: Please, post more information. There's no information on how the src is stored in the database and no code showing how it's retrieved.

Comment: I edited the post